# Update database from datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net, datagridview, oledb

I have googled a lot on updating datagridview to database after editing using the adapter. I referred to several websites that gave me similar examples like the one below. However, I'm getting the "ArgumentNullException was unhandled" error at the first line of my button2_Click.

I am new to programming and I have been taught to declare the adapter as a global, and I did. Why am I still getting null value? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
DataTable dt;
DataSet ds;
OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Bind button
    string txt = textBox1.Text;

    string strOleDbConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Project.mdb";
    string strSqlStatement = string.Empty;
    strSqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM jiahe WHERE [User] = '" + txt + "'";
    OleDbConnection objConnection = new OleDbConnection(strOleDbConnectionString);
    objAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSqlStatement, objConnection);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
    objAdapter.Fill(ds);

    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;           

    try
    {
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record found.");
        }
        else
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid input!");
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error!");
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    objAdapter.Update(ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's simply a confusion between the variables in different scopes. The `ds` you use in the second `button_click`  **is not the same** data set you use to populate a grid . Make them the **exactly same instance** and it will, most likely work.

**Edit**

to make so *should be* enough to write instead of

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
objAdapter.Fill(ds);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];`
```

This

```
ds = new DataSet();
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
objAdapter.Fill(ds);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];`
```

Comment: How do I make them the exact same instance? Wouldn't making it a global variable do the job?

Comment: Thank you. Now I got it pointing to the same ds. BUT, I have another error "InvalidOperationException was unhandled". It says 'Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.' Why is the Update command not valid? Please help!

Comment: @diaz: you didn't difine `update command`  for adapter. Adapter has no idea what `sql` query to run against DB in order to update. There is no magic and it's easy, but you need to read at least this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and I fixed it by trying this:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
objAdapter.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```